# PHP :Printing Associative Array with nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a multidimensional array that contains associative array and in associative array i have a key named 'opt' that contains an array. I looped through the whole multidimensional array. I wanna make it more simplified and **get rid of** **checking whether the key is 'opt' or not** because if i have more keys that contain array then i have to apply check for all keys that contain array.I don't wanna do that and wanna do in more technical way.
in short how to check while looping through the array that the $value contains an array.

```
$myArr=array(
    array(
        'question' => 'First Question',
        'opt' => array('A','B','c','D'),
        'ans' => '3'
    ),
    array(
        'question' => 'Second Question',
        'opt' => array('A','B','c','D'),
        'ans' => '1'
    )
);
for($i=0; $i<count($myArr); $i++)
{
    foreach ($myArr[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key!='opt') {
            echo $value . "<br/>";
        }
        else{
            for($ii=0; $ii<count($value); $ii++)
            {
                echo $value[$ii] . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just wanna make it more simplified. I'm putting it in in JSON file(Done it successfully).

Comment: Add you expected output in your question, So we can get more idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function and display anything using `foreach`, like so:

```
function display_array($arr){
    if(gettype($arr) == 'array'){
        foreach($arr as $v){
            display_array($v);
        }
    }else{
        echo $arr . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
display_array($myArr);
```

The output is the same as with your code. Check it out [here](https://3v4l.org/3GelD).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your desired output... The easiest way of "printing" this array in a nice formatted fashion is:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

That might not serve a presentation for the user, but if it's just about "viewing" the result yourself, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can print nested arrays easily with the following class. It runs recursively so that it doesn't matter how many nested arrays, on how many levels you have.

```
<?php

class Debug
{
    public static function errorLog($text)
    {
        $lines = Debug::arrayToTextLines($text);
        foreach ($lines as $value) {
            error_log($value);
        }
    }

    public static function echo($text)
    {
        $lines = Debug::arrayToTextLines($text);
        foreach ($lines as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }

    public static function arrayToTextLines($array, $nestLevel = 0)
    {
        $resultLines = array();
        $margin = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nestLevel; $i++) {
            $margin = "  " . $margin;
        }

        if (gettype($array) == 'array') {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $subValues = Debug::arrayToTextLines($value, $nestLevel + 1);
                if (count($subValues) > 1) {
                    $resultLines[] = $margin . $key . " => ";
                    $resultLines = array_merge($resultLines, $subValues);
                } else {
                    $resultLines[] = $margin . $key . " => " . $value;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $resultLines[] = $margin . $array;
        }

        return $resultLines;
    }
}
```